# product.map is not a function error in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to fetch data from the rest API to front end. Here I used getStaticProps() but when I want to map the data from the props it shows not function.I have inspected it the data I get in return is an array so it should be able to do map operation.

```
    import {
        Button,
        Card,
        CardActionArea,
        CardActions,
        CardContent,
        CardMedia,
        Grid,
        Typography,
    } from '@material-ui/core';
    
    import Layout from '../components/Layout';
    
    import data from '../utils/data';
    
    import NextLink from 'next/link';
    
    export const getStaticProps = async () => {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/products');
        const data = await res.json();
        
        return {
            props: {
                products: data
            },
        };
        
    
    };
    
    export default function Home({ products }) {
        console.log(products);
        
        return (
            <Layout>
                <div>
                    <h1>Products</h1>
                    <Grid container spacing={3}>
                        {products.map((product) => (
                            <Grid item md={4} key={product.name}>
                                <Card>
                                    <NextLink
                                        href={`/product/${product.slug}`}
                                        passHref
                                    >
                                        <CardActionArea>
                                            <CardMedia
                                                component="img"
                                                image={product.image}
                                                title={product.name}
                                            ></CardMedia>
                                            <CardContent>
                                                <Typography>
                                                    {product.name}
                                                </Typography>
                                            </CardContent>
                                        </CardActionArea>
                                        <CardActions>
                                            <Typography>
                                                ${product.price}
                                            </Typography>
                                            <Button size="medium" color="secondary">
                                                Make a BID{' '}
                                            </Button>
                                        </CardActions>
                                    </NextLink>
                                </Card>
                            </Grid>
                        ))}
                    </Grid>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
```

Here is my code where I am fetching.You can see here I have created a home product page I want to display data that I am getting from rest api.

Comment: Can you share an example of what `products` looks like if you log it out?  Even just dummy data that matches the structure? Also, just to be clear the error is `products.map` is not a function right?  Not `product.map` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment sir i have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution :
I am passing a object data then I am calling products of the data object that makes the products an array and it solves.

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
   const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/products');
   const data = await res.json();

   return {
       props: {
           data
       },
   };
};
```

data.products.map((product)